# I have a webpage made in wordpress which shows the wrong metadata in google, how can I change this?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I am reasonably new to word press and I am currently building my site. If you go to the google search page [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=james%20novis%20tuition%20pricing&oq=james%20novis%20tuition%20pricing&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.9794j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

You can see that the Pricing webpage shows information from New York.

I desperately need to change this as it may put potential customers off with me being in England.

Can anyone help please. I have tried following tutorials with Yoast but cannot see the "advaced settings option" and therefore cannot follow the tutorials.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following step

1. List item Log in to your WordPress website. When you're logged in, you will be in your 'Dashboard'. On the left-hand side, you will see a menu. In that menu, click on 'SEO'.
2. The ‘SEO’ settings will expand providing you additional options. Click on [Search Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlViQ.png)
3. Under the 'General' tab, check the box "Enable force rewrite titles". This is not available when your theme already supports dynamic titles as [discussed Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXscp.png)
4. Save changes.

**Updated:**
In Yost SEO Plugin 7.2 version, you can see that option[Version 7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0rht.png). but today morning i updated plugin, that time it's not showing on this.[Version 7.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTeDp.png). You need to install 7.2 version for this.

Comment: Hi I have followed the steps you suggestg but there is no "Enable force rewrite option" under the general tab. Is this a feature which is only available in the pro version?

Comment: I update my answer, This Feature available in Free Version. (currently, i'm using free version)